# Maintain map zoom level across Destroy/Create

Tags: google-maps

I am using:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map))
       .getMap();
```

to create my map view. I want to maintain the users current choice for zoom level across the Destroy/Create activities, but I have been unable to determine what the current zoom level is.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

to get the current zoom level and then store it in Preferences